# Error while running npm-start in react js. Tried installing sass but still not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path /home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!     path: '/home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/vishu/Downloads/React-JS-BookList-master/booklist/node_modules/.node-sass.DELETE/vendor/linux-x64-88',
npm ERR!   parent: 'booklist'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vishu/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T17_52_06_142Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue.
Either give your current user access to the folders listed or try running it as sudo.

Comment: tried sudo npm-install still not working, showing same error